# How to connect a Tandy Color Computer to a Composite Monitor?

Tags: video, coco

Ok, I'll admit I'm out of my element on this one.  I'm an Atari/Commodore/Apple guy, but I have this Tandy color computer kicking around and a spare Amdek Composite monitor and I thought they would make a nice pair.  Unfortunately, it seems that the Color Computer (which I think is a CoCo2) only outputs RF?  That can't be right, can it?

What is the generally accepted best practice for connecting a composite monitor to an old Tandy?  I know I could get a TV for it, or loop the RF through a VCR, but I was looking for a more elegant solution - I'm game to homebrew if the circuitry isn't too complex.

I did some half-hearted googling, but its more fun to ask here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The TRS-80 Color Computer 1 and Color Computer 2 only supported RF output to a TV. It wasn't until the CoCo 3 that both composite and RGB output were added - RGB being essential for the new 80-column text and higher resolution graphics.

Naturally, there are composite monitor-compatible signals inside the CoCo 2, upstream of the in built RF modulator. And some people have created [custom PCB adapters](https://thezippsterzone.com/2018/10/28/coco2-composite-a-v-modulator-replacements/) to output composite. This PCB is cool in that it replaces the RF modulator in the CoCo 2 and can be installed without modifications to the computer case.

Of course, the CoCo 3 is superior in many ways, not just the video output ports and resolution. But if you have no aspirations to run [OS-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-9) software, then the CoCo 2 is good for the native software library.

If you are more interested in making significant investment in the CoCo 2, rather than searching for a CoCo 3, then you *might* be able to acquire the new [COCOVGA adapter](http://cocovga.com/). This is a much fancier video enhancer that also includes new graphics modes, more colors, and 64-column text.

Comment: It's worth noting that retrocomputing stack exchange regular Bruce Abbott has a [design for a CoCo 2 composite adapter](http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/coco_s-video.html) on his web site, which could be helpful.

Comment: A bit late but I wanted to object to this statement "if you have no aspirations to run OS-9 software, then the CoCo 2 is good" as it is not true.  CoCo 2 ran OS-9 Level One perfectly well (I was a very happy user/programmer of OS-9 Level One for many years, and never saw the need to upgrade to CoCo 3).

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively, you could have the awesome CoCoVGA installed in your CoCo2 and hook it up to any VGA monitor. It will add a plethora of colours and other options the original never had!

http://cocovga.com/